# Thoughts Required ? Am i cleaning my ViewModel class properly?

Tags: android, mvvm, clean-architecture

I want to clean my viewmodel class by using [raywenderlich approach](https://www.raywenderlich.com/636803-mvvm-and-databinding-android-design-patterns).

So in this blog they have written that we there is a binder component which is not for user. but i want to use this class as helper class for viewmodel.

[image]

Here I am creating a class which i termed as Binder class for ViewModel, which my view will use to make contact with ViewModel class.

[image]

Now my Binder class is helping me in cleaning my ViewModel class like,
[image]

**Edited :**

So my View class will be like :

```
class UserDetailView : AppCompatActivity(), UiCallbacks {
    lateinit var screenCallbacks: ScreenCallbacks;
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        screenCallbacks = UserDetailBinder(this).bindLayout(R.layout.activity_learn_binding)
        screenCallbacks.loadData()
    }

    override fun onUserNameChanged(userName: String) {

    }
}
```

And my Binder class will be like :

```
class UserDetailBinder(private val userDetailView: UserDetailView) : ScreenCallbacks, ViewModelController {

    private val userDetailObservers = UserDetailViewState(userDetailView)

    init {
        userDetailObservers.observe(userDetailView)
    }

    fun bindLayout(layout: Int): ScreenCallbacks {
        binding<com.bold.job.databinding.ActivityLearnBindingBinding, OwnViewModel>(userDetailView, layout).let {
            var viewModel = viewModel(userDetailView, OwnViewModel::class.java)
            it.viewModel = viewModel
        }
        return this
    }

    override fun loadData() {

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you reference your Binder class? Does your `Activity/Fragment` holds reference to it or just used as *Utilized* `ViewModel` class? In such case, `ViewModels` are handled by `ViewModelProviders` for giving you exact object across **configuration changes**, How does your Binder class handle that?

Comment: hi @JeelVankhede, please go through my edited code.

Comment: Looks promising but I think you're over-engineering core concept of **MVVM** *(in my opinion)*.

Comment: It will help a lot in maintaining viewmodel, because viewmodel can become a 1000 lines class easilt I think

Comment: Yeah in such case, you're good to go.. but be aware that you don't end up holding references to your Views inside Your Binder, because your ViewModel might survive configuration changes if used from architecture component but you'll have to handle it for your Binders. So all is about how you initialise stuffs.

Comment: Although I appreciate your approach and this question.